# Parsing Typed XML with a default namespace and inconsistent root node

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, xml, xquery

I have a structured, typed xml file.

```
<WebService xmlns="http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon">
 <NewLeads>
  <OutputSchema>
  <root xmlns="" type="array">
   <item type="object">
   <SaleProperty type="object">
    <Type type="string">Freehold</Type>
    <PostDistrict type="string">xxx</PostDistrict>
    <Address type="string">address</Address>
     <Value type="number">17.0</Value>
   </SaleProperty>
   <Transaction type="string">SaleOnly</Transaction>
   <Quote type="object">
    <Sale type="object">
     <Fees type="number">450.0</Fees>
     <Disbursements type="number">0.0</Disbursements>
     <StampDuty type="number">0.0</StampDuty>
     <Total type="number">450.0</Total>
    </Sale>
   <Discount type="number">0.0</Discount>
   <VAT type="number">90.0</VAT>
   <Total type="number">540.0</Total>
  </Quote>
  <MoverId type="number">12345678</MoverId>
  <Name type="string">Mr AS</Name>
  <Email type="string">as@yahoo.ppp</Email>
  <Telephone type="string">0123456789</Telephone>
  <Comments type="string">Joint ownership</Comments>
  <EstimatedMoveDate type="string">2015-11-25T05:57:00</EstimatedMoveDate>
  <Charge type="number">4.99</Charge>
  <ChargeStatus type="string">Chargeable</ChargeStatus>
 </item>
</root>
</OutputSchema></NewLeads></WebService>
```

Additionally, object SaleProperty may be missing, instead may be object PurchaseProperty. Similarly, object Quote can contain Sale, Purchase, Remortgage objects or sale and Purchase simultaneously
I can't find any tips on inserting it into one table via xquery on SQL Server 2012. Basic problem is that every time I'm building query to extract even one value (i.e. Transaction) only thing except errors I get is empty string.

my sample query (based on MSDN examples):

```
SELECT t.c.value('(.)[1]','varchar(50)') as type
from @ixml.nodes('/root/item/transaction') as t(c)
```

I would like to have an example how to insert this xml into table (where every possible element has it's own column.

I assume that problem is with namespaces and strong typing of the xml. However, this is what I get from web service. I work on xml both missing and containing second xmlns declaration in root element, as well as with structure trimmed down to just root.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The three problems with your XQuery that I can see are (and none of this has anything to do with it being Typed XML):

1. You are not specifying the correct path to the `/root` node. It should be:

   ```sql
   SELECT t.c.value('(.)[1]','varchar(50)') as type
   from @ixml.nodes('/WebService/NewLeads/OutputSchema/root/item/transaction') as t(c)
   ```
2. XML is case-sensitive so you need to use an upper-case "T" for the "Transaction" node:

   ```sql
   SELECT t.c.value('(.)[1]','varchar(50)') as type
   from @ixml.nodes('/WebService/NewLeads/OutputSchema/root/item/Transaction') as t(c)
   ```
3. While those fixes would probably get you 1 value back (in this case, it should be "SaleOnly"), it won't iterate through the "item" nodes because you were too specific in the path supplied to the `.nodes()` function. Instead, the final node of that specification should be "item", which is what you want to iterate through. And in that case, you move the "Transaction" part up to the `.value()` function:

   ```sql
   SELECT t.c.value('(./Transaction)[1]','varchar(50)') as type
   from @ixml.nodes('/WebService/NewLeads/OutputSchema/root/item') as t(c)
   ```

Regarding the statement of:

> I work on xml both missing and containing second xmlns declaration in root element, as well as with structure trimmed down to just root.

The "structure trimmed down to just root" should be handleable by removing everything between the first `/` and the `/` right before `/root...` (i.e. the `WebService/NewLeads/OutputSchema`). So the resulting path would be:

```sql
from @ixml.nodes('//root/item') as t(c)
```

**NOTE:**
I am not able to get this to work 100% with the namespace declared in the `<WebService>` element (*please see additional notes as this is no longer the case*). Taking that out makes it work. Giving it a prefix, such as `xmlns:something="http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon"` makes it work, but then that needs to be declared in the methods.  The only way I can get it to work right now is by declaring the default namespace in each XML function (`.nodes` and `.value`) as follows:

```sql
SELECT t.c.value('declare default element namespace "http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon";
                  (./Transaction)[1]','varchar(50)') as [type]
from @ixml.nodes('declare default element namespace "http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon";
                  /WebService/NewLeads/OutputSchema/root/item') as t(c)
```

**NOTE 2:**
Even better, you can use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` to declare one or more namespaces to use for the entire query, so no need to define in each XML function. The following both work:

```sql
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon')
SELECT t.c.value('(./Transaction)[1]','varchar(50)') as [type]
from @ixml.nodes('/WebService/NewLeads/OutputSchema/root/item') as t(c)


;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon')
SELECT t.c.value('(./Transaction)[1]','varchar(50)') as [type]
from @ixml.nodes('//root/item') as t(c)
```

However, just keep in mind that if the document is missing the `<WebService xmlns="http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon">` element and hence has no default namespace, then you need to remove the `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES` part. Of course, if the `<root>` element has its own default namespace, then maybe you will need to keep it. You can play around with it until it works, now that you know the connection between these pieces.

**NOTE 3:**
If you do end up having two default namespaces declared -- one in the `<WebService>` element and one in the `<root>` element -- then you need to specify the URI noted in `<root xmlns="bob">` *and* the `//` syntax instead of the fully-qualified path.  So if your XML looked like:

```xml
<WebService xmlns="http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon">
 <NewLeads>
  <OutputSchema>
  <root xmlns="http://someplace" type="array">
```

You would then use:

```sql
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://someplace')
SELECT t.c.value('(./Transaction)[1]','varchar(50)') as [type]
from @ixml.nodes('//root/item') as t(c)
```

But that won't help if you do have the `<WebService>` element and yet the `<root>` element is missing the `xmlns` declaration. In that case you still need to specify the namespace noted in the `<WebService>` element. Fun, fun, fun :-).

**NOTE 4:**
Even more better: incorporating something mentioned in @wBob's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/121912/30859), we can actually get rid of the `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES` clause, and instead use a namespace wildcard. You just need to prefix *every* node of *every* XML function with `*:`. Now the query should look as follows:

```sql
SELECT t.c.value('(./*:Transaction)[1]','varchar(50)') AS [type],
       t.c.value('(./*:SaleProperty/*:PostDistrict)[1]','varchar(50)') AS [PostDistrict]
FROM  @ixml.nodes('//*:root/*:item') t(c);
```

Doing this means that the query works in all of your scenarios:

1. Full structure starting with "WebService" node, second xmlns declaration:

   ```xml
   <WebService xmlns="http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon">
     <NewLeads>
       <OutputSchema>
         <root xmlns="uri" type="array">
   ```
2. Full structure starting with "WebService" node, single xmlns declaration:

   ```xml
   <WebService xmlns="http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon">
     <NewLeads>
       <OutputSchema>
         <root type="array">
   ```
3. Trimmed down structure starting with "root" node, single xmlns declaration:

   ```xml
   <root xmlns="uri" type="array">
   ```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64704/discussion-on-answer-by-solomon-rutzky-parsing-typed-xml-with-a-default-namespac).

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to dump out all the element values as rows irrespective of the namespace, then you can use a namespace wildcard, eg:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<WebService xmlns="http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon">
    <NewLeads>
        <OutputSchema>
            <root xmlns="" type="array">
                <item type="object">
                    <SaleProperty type="object">
                        <Type type="string">Freehold</Type>
                        <PostDistrict type="string">xxx</PostDistrict>
                        <Address type="string">address</Address>
                        <Value type="number">17.0</Value>
                    </SaleProperty>
                    <Transaction type="string">SaleOnly</Transaction>
                    <Quote type="object">
                        <Sale type="object">
                            <Fees type="number">450.0</Fees>
                            <Disbursements type="number">0.0</Disbursements>
                            <StampDuty type="number">0.0</StampDuty>
                            <Total type="number">450.0</Total>
                        </Sale>
                        <Discount type="number">0.0</Discount>
                        <VAT type="number">90.0</VAT>
                        <Total type="number">540.0</Total>
                    </Quote>
                    <MoverId type="number">12345678</MoverId>
                    <Name type="string">Mr AS</Name>
                    <Email type="string">as@yahoo.ppp</Email>
                    <Telephone type="string">0123456789</Telephone>
                    <Comments type="string">Joint ownership</Comments>
                    <EstimatedMoveDate type="string">2015-11-25T05:57:00</EstimatedMoveDate>
                    <Charge type="number">4.99</Charge>
                    <ChargeStatus type="string">Chargeable</ChargeStatus>
                </item>
            </root>
        </OutputSchema>
    </NewLeads>
</WebService>'


-- Show all elements and their values irrespective of namespace
SELECT 
    x.y.value('local-name(..)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') parentElementName,
    x.y.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') elementName,
    x.y.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') elementValue
FROM @xml.nodes('//*[not(*)]') AS x(y)


SELECT 
    ws.c.value('local-name(..)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') parentElementName,
    ws.c.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') elementName,
    ws.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') elementValue
FROM @xml.nodes('*:WebService/*:NewLeads/*:OutputSchema/*:root/*:item/*[not(*)]') AS ws(c)
```

Result:

[image: Results]

You could then do something like dynamic pivot if you need to turn this into columns.  If you do want to specify elements explicitly you can use a similar technique.

Judging from your question you probably need to spend more time learning about XML namespaces, so start here:

**Adding Namespaces Using WITH XMLNAMESPACES**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx

Comment: Interesting. I have never seen wildcards used for namespaces before. +1 for that :-).

Comment: @wBob - thank you for that insights. as srutzky's, they are invaluable. Mainly because of the working example. I spent literally days going over internet's resources on that and came up short for the task. You won't believe how much I've learned from your answers.

You are correct that I had very little to do with xml before. Check that: with xml namespaces and SQL. Frankly I had really no idea the SQL Server is a better xml parser and extraction/manipulation tool than one used for that for more than a year (Orbis Taskcentre). Funny. But as I say: every day something new.

Comment: No problem.  Don't be afraid to ask questions as there are some very knowledgeable guys here on that topic eg @MikaelEriksson.  When I was learning about SQL Server XML and XQuery this article really helped me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122(SQL.90).aspx